# Close Port 587 - Ramifications?

Tags: email, smtp, authentication, port

Our recent PCI scan failed because "Plaintext authentication is allowed over unencrypted channel on SMTP." As such, our tech support suggested to close port 587.

What are the effects of closing port 587, and will it negatively affect sending/receiving emails?

Comment: Presumably the scan identified a particular machine (or machines) that were vulnerable on port 587.  Is the machine in question a mail server?  Do you have any mail servers on-premise, or do you use external mail servers, e.g., Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Port 587 is typically the port used for SMTP submissions by email clients. It usually uses TLS encryption as a security measure.

Port 25 is the universal port for email exchange between servers on the internet.

Email can be submitted via either port, in either an encrypted or unencrypted fashion, depending on your policy.

If you disable port 587, depending on your use case, you may actually be hurting your security by preventing an email client from communicating securely.

The proper action is to REQUIRE TLS(encrypted) connections on port 587, by changing your email server policies. This should satisfy the requirement, and eliminate the warning.

You should also support and allow TLS connections on port 25. Servers that support it will use it to deliver email securely. However, you can’t require it on port 25 as you will break the exchange of email.

Depending on your use case, you could potentially close port 587 if you do not have any clients or servers using the port to deliver email. This would be the case in something like an MS Exchange / Outlook setup that uses MAPI over HTTPS. But in almost every other type of email server setup, port 587 is used exclusively by the email client to submit secure emails to the server and obviously shouldn’t be closed.

Comment: How can determine whether I have clients or servers using port 587 to deliver mail?  And if they do, how can I pass the next PCI scan?

Comment: You didn’t give any details about your server/client setup. If it’s not exchange and outlook then you are almost certainly using port 587. This can be seen in your SMTP settings in your email client. And if you’re not using port 587 and TLS you should be. That’s why your PCI scan is flagging this. I already said how to eliminate the PCI failure - change your email server policy to only allow TLS connections on port 587.

Comment: @ArvyS. Your sysadmin should know which of your servers are supposed to be running email server software. If they don't, they should now use the PCI scan output to check through each server and verify what it is running and document them.

Comment: Currently, for our Secure SSL/TLS Settings, we are using port SMTP Port 465 as our Outgoing Server (for non-SSL it's Port 25). Should this be modified?

Comment: No, in the interest of not over complicating the answer, I left out the less common port 465 which is the actual “secure SMTP” port and will always require SSL/TLS by default. If your clients are using this already, then you can close 587. However, forcing TLS encryption on port 587 is really all the is required to meet your PCI requirements. Just make sure all your email clients really are using port 465 in their SMTP settings.